# Faster way to Clip and Typecast RGB images

Tags: python, image-processing, clip

i'm trying to process a video at 30 FPS, which gives me 33ms to process each frame, i've already used aboout 20ms in image processing but my biggest bottleneck is the conversion.

The frames are two RGB images with shape = (540, 1787, 3), dtype = float32 each, i need to clip the image from 0 to 255 and convert it to dtype uint8.

Currently i'm using this code for convertion:

```
self.imgFrame = self.imgConcat.clip(min = 0, max = 255).astype(np.uint8)
self.imgMotio = self.imgDiff.clip(min = 0, max = 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

These two lines add up to about 90ms.
Just casting with astype(np.uint8) gives overflow values and is only noise
I've tried numba as suggested here: https://jcristharif.com/numba-overload.html but didn't get it to work nor modify it
I'm happy to reduce the FPS to 20 or even 15 but the clipping don't let me get past 10

I was thinking about to starting a thread just for clipping but im almost sure it won't help

Any suggestions or a way to just cast it trimming the values to (0, 255)?

Comment: Why are you using Python if you need real-time performance?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i have made everything using np.uint8.

When dealing with subtraction, i first casted the images from np.uint8 to np.int16

Now, np.clip(min = 0, max = 255).astype(np.uint8) is way faster for some reason

Those two lines of code now execute in about 10ms instead of 90